# Configure error "g++ version cannot be determined"

Tags: gcc, g++, configure

I am relatively new to using Ubuntu (ver. 18.04) and am trying to install a software package for research work. the package can be obtained from https://github.com/chetzer-ncpa/ncpaprop When i try to run the ./configure  i get this as a response:

```
checking for bash... /bin/bash
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for apt-get... apt-get
configure: enable-auto-dependencies =
configure: enable-library-guess =
checking for g++-4... no
checking for g++... g++
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking for g++-4... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc-4... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
configure: error: in `/home/trevor/Desktop/plz':
configure: error: g++ version cannot be determined
See `config.log' for more details
```

the config.log file is:

```
    This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by NCPA Propagation Modeling Suite configure 1.3.20, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = trevor-VirtualBox
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.0.0-31-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2288: checking for bash
configure:2306: found /bin/bash
configure:2318: result: /bin/bash
configure:2336: checking for perl
configure:2354: found /usr/bin/perl
configure:2366: result: /usr/bin/perl
configure:2438: checking for ranlib
configure:2454: found /usr/bin/ranlib
configure:2465: result: ranlib
configure:2521: checking build system type
configure:2535: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2555: checking host system type
configure:2568: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2650: checking for apt-get
configure:2666: found /usr/bin/apt-get
configure:2677: result: apt-get
configure:2698: enable-auto-dependencies = 
configure:2700: enable-library-guess = 
configure:2732: checking for g++-4
configure:2762: result: no
configure:2732: checking for g++
configure:2748: found /usr/bin/g++
configure:2759: result: g++
configure:2885: checking for gfortran
configure:2901: found /usr/bin/gfortran
configure:2912: result: gfortran
configure:3098: checking for g++-4
configure:3128: result: no
configure:3098: checking for g++
configure:3114: found /usr/bin/g++
configure:3125: result: g++
configure:3152: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:3161: g++ --version >&5
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3172: $? = 0
configure:3161: g++ -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 
configure:3172: $? = 0
configure:3161: g++ -V >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3172: $? = 1
configure:3161: g++ -qversion >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3172: $? = 1
configure:3192: checking whether the C++ compiler works
configure:3214: g++    conftest.cpp  >&5
configure:3218: $? = 0
configure:3266: result: yes
configure:3269: checking for C++ compiler default output file name
configure:3271: result: a.out
configure:3277: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3284: g++ -o conftest    conftest.cpp  >&5
configure:3288: $? = 0
configure:3310: result: 
configure:3332: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3340: g++ -o conftest    conftest.cpp  >&5
configure:3344: $? = 0
configure:3351: ./conftest
configure:3355: $? = 0
configure:3370: result: no
configure:3375: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3397: g++ -c   conftest.cpp >&5
configure:3401: $? = 0
configure:3422: result: o
configure:3426: checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler
configure:3445: g++ -c   conftest.cpp >&5
configure:3445: $? = 0
configure:3454: result: yes
configure:3463: checking whether g++ accepts -g
configure:3483: g++ -c -g  conftest.cpp >&5
configure:3483: $? = 0
configure:3524: result: yes
configure:3601: checking for gcc-4
configure:3631: result: no
configure:3601: checking for gcc
configure:3617: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3628: result: gcc
configure:3659: checking for C compiler version
configure:3668: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3679: $? = 0
configure:3668: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 
configure:3679: $? = 0
configure:3668: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3679: $? = 1
configure:3668: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3679: $? = 1
configure:3683: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:3702: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:3702: $? = 0
configure:3711: result: yes
configure:3720: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:3740: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:3740: $? = 0
configure:3781: result: yes
configure:3798: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:3861: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:3861: $? = 0
configure:3874: result: none needed
configure:3947: checking for gfortran
configure:3963: found /usr/bin/gfortran
configure:3974: result: gfortran
configure:4000: checking for Fortran compiler version
configure:4009: gfortran --version >&5
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4020: $? = 0
configure:4009: gfortran -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 
configure:4020: $? = 0
configure:4009: gfortran -V >&5
gfortran: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4020: $? = 1
configure:4009: gfortran -qversion >&5
gfortran: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4020: $? = 1
configure:4029: checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler
configure:4042: gfortran -c   conftest.F >&5
configure:4042: $? = 0
configure:4051: result: yes
configure:4057: checking whether gfortran accepts -g
configure:4068: gfortran -c -g  conftest.f >&5
configure:4068: $? = 0
configure:4076: result: yes
configure:4110: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:4141: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:4141: $? = 0
configure:4155: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:9:10: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:4155: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "NCPA Propagation Modeling Suite"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "ncpaprop"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.3.20"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "NCPA Propagation Modeling Suite 1.3.20"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "claus@olemiss.edu"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:4180: result: gcc -E
configure:4200: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:4200: $? = 0
configure:4214: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:9:10: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:4214: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "NCPA Propagation Modeling Suite"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "ncpaprop"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.3.20"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "NCPA Propagation Modeling Suite 1.3.20"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "claus@olemiss.edu"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:4248: error: in `/home/trevor/Downloads/ncpaprop-master':
configure:4250: error: g++ version cannot be determined
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_cxx_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_FC_set=
ac_cv_env_FC_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_fc_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_BASHPATH=/bin/bash
ac_cv_path_PERLPATH=/usr/bin/perl
ac_cv_prog_CPP='gcc -E'
ac_cv_prog_CXX_TEST=g++
ac_cv_prog_FC_TEST=gfortran
ac_cv_prog_PACKMAN=apt-get
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CXX=g++
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_FC=gfortran
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_RANLIB=ranlib
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_cxx_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_fc_g=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AWK=''
BASHPATH='/bin/bash'
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS='-g -O2'
CPP='gcc -E'
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='g++'
CXXFLAGS='-g -O2'
CXX_TEST='g++'
DEFS=''
DORUFLAGS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FC='gfortran'
FCFLAGS='-g -O2'
FC_TEST='gfortran'
GREP=''
INCLUDEFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MPICXX=''
OBJEXT='o'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='claus@olemiss.edu'
PACKAGE_NAME='NCPA Propagation Modeling Suite'
PACKAGE_STRING='NCPA Propagation Modeling Suite 1.3.20'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='ncpaprop'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.3.20'
PACKMAN='apt-get'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERLPATH='/usr/bin/perl'
PETSC_ARCH_COMPLEX=''
PETSC_ARCH_REAL=''
PETSC_DIR=''
PETSC_OS=''
PETSC_USE_MPI=''
PETSC_USE_SHARED_LIBRARIES='--with-shared-libraries'
PETSC_VERSION=''
POW_LIB=''
RANLIB='ranlib'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SLEPC_DIR=''
SLEPC_USE_MPI=''
SLEPC_VERSION=''
STATICLIBS=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX='g++'
ac_ct_FC='gfortran'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "NCPA Propagation Modeling Suite"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "ncpaprop"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.3.20"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "NCPA Propagation Modeling Suite 1.3.20"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "claus@olemiss.edu"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 1
```

any insight into this would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Have you checked that you really have `g++` installed? Try `g++ --version` in a terminal. If it's not installed, do `sudo apt install g++` to install it.

Comment: The issue seems to be that the `configure` script expects `g++ -dumpversion` to produce an output of the form `major.minor`; it appears that since gcc-7 `-dumpversion` only outputs the major version and there is a new option `-dumpfullversion` that gives the expected old output. See for example [gcc dumpversion #160](https://github.com/smanders/externpro/issues/160). I'm not sure the best way to work around that.

Comment: @Elias yes, It seems the issue was the configure script not finding the same version for gcc, g++ and gfortran. But using Ulis answer from below the configure script ran successfully. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @steeldriver It seems Uli's response did the trick. Thank your for your reply!

Comment: @LvnTrvr yes using *any* version of gcc/g++/gfortran prior to 7 should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install -y g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 gfortran-4.8
./configure CXX=g++-4.8 CC=gcc-4.8 FC=gfortran-4.8
make
```

Comment: This worked, the configure script ran succesfully and I am now running through the make script! Thank you very much!