# Can't install opencv 2.4.9 on Ubuntu 18.04, get CXXCompiler error

Tags: opencv

I am trying to install opencv 2.4.9 on Ubuntu 18 to support an older software. After downloading the version from the sourceforge link, I create a build folder and run the following cmake command.

```
cmake -D WITH_TBB=OFF -D WITH_V4L=OFF -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF -D  WITH_FFMPEG=OFF -D WITH_1394=OFF -D WITH_LIBV4L=OFF ..
```

I get the following errors:

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake:85 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:77 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake:86 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:77 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake:89 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: "*100 + ": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_TIMES, expecting exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER (1)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:77 (include)
```

I suspected that it could be to do with an old version of cmake but I have cmake version 3.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue related to a change in the format of `g++ -dumpversion`: see for example [OpenCV SuperBuild fails with gcc 7+](https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/otb/issues/1602). Based on a quick test, it seems to be possible to workaround by editing the `OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake` file, changing `-dumpversion` to `-dumpfullversion`. So for example if you are running `cmake` from an out-of-tree `build` subdirectory:

```
sed -i.bak 's/dumpversion/dumpfullversion/' ../cmake/OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake
```

Alternatively, install an older g++ version and tell `cmake` to use it via the `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` flag as suggested here [Configure error “g++ version cannot be determined”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181040/configure-error-g-version-cannot-be-determined)